# Django Admin: Dropdown selecting ContentTypes & Generic Relationships

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a generic relationship in my model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    content_type = ...
    object_id = ...
    content_object = ...

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

I understand with `GenericTabularInline` I could insert this as an inline generic object into a different admin form. To clarify, this is not what I am looking for.

My question is: Given a FooAdmin above, now can I have the detail admin view provide a dropdown selector for object_id/content_object instead of having it as a raw ID field (which is very inconvenient)?